# No Values - Azure Stream Analytics - JSON Input format

Tags: json, string, powerbi

I cant do the JSON string right so that Stream Analytics put the Values to PowerBi.

This is what it looks like:

```
(catched in Device Explorer)
20/04/2021 12:28:33> Device: [Portal00], Data:[{"Timestamp":"2021-04-20T10:28:28","Groupname":"FHV-PR2021","Values":{"Sensor01":148.31768798828126,"Sensor02":175.01487731933595,"Sensor03":145.35133361816407}}]Properties:
'readpipe': ''
```

[only Timestamp and Count of Records available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXfGp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
20/04/2021 13:37:37> Device: [Portal00], Data:[{"Timestamp":"2021-04-20T11:37:31","Groupname":"FHV-PR2021","PR00X":51.10093688964844,"PR00Y":8.89906120300293,"PR00Z":1.4831769466400147}]Properties:
'readpipe': ''

Edit the JSON String so that there are no Values together and define your Query for that String. Now PowerBi gets the right information: Time, X,Y and Z Position of my Robot.

[New Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHNF7.png)